# Overriding VS 2017's docker-compose dynamically created entrypoint

Tags: docker, docker-compose, visual-studio-2017

When using the integrated docker-compose structure in Visual Studio 2017, the system provides visibility to a two-tiered docker-compose structure.

```
docker-compose.yml and docker-compose.override.yml
```

Settings in the override take precedent over those in the former file.  When the file is actually executed, it includes a third, auto-generated Docker compose file ...

```
docker-compose.vs.*configuration*.g.yml
```

This latter file contains mostly values related to debugging interactions and mapping volumes in for code you want.  Generally, you wouldn't want to change any of these.

One thing that it does by default is to set the entrypoint which ends up becoming the command for the container.  As this file is applied last (after the compose file and the override, it is holding precedence over the other two resulting in not being able to override that entrypoint.

Is there a way around this?