# Override visual studio docker compose entrypoint

Tags: visual-studio-2017, docker-compose

We are using the visual studio 2017 tools for docker. I have noticed VS keeps generating these default partial files named similar to docker-compose.vs.release.g.yml. these files have an entrypoint in them that launches the app and the debugger. This would all be fine, but I have a custom entrypoint and this line keeps overwriting my entrypoint in docker-compose.override.yml because of the order VS applies the files. I have tried updating these files specifically, but my changes get overwritten. I have also found this question ([Overriding VS 2017's docker-compose dynamically created entrypoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46331920/overriding-vs-2017s-docker-compose-dynamically-created-entrypoint)) which is basically the same, but there was no answer.

Comment: I think you should create docker-compose.yml by yourself

Comment: I do have docker compose files, when you add docker support to the VS2017 project, ti creates a docker-compose.yml and docker-compose.override.yml file. these ones are filled out with my own information like environment variables ,etc. I have even added the entrypoint setting to these files, but entrypoint is always overridden by these generated files that VS used when it runs. I don't have direct access to modify how it builds its docker-compose commands. I'm just trying to debug my application.
I have tried deleting the files in question but VS just recreates them.